# Is there an SE site for latex modelling/moulding/casting?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

You know, where you have some hideously ugly gnome and want more copies of it, so you paint it with latex, fill it with plaster.. etc

I thought it would be arts and crafts, but I didn't find any tags obviously related to modelling, casting, mo(u)lding there...

Comment: You could ask on the site meta if it's topical; I would expect it to be, and the presence or absence of a tag tells you less about topicality than one might expect.

Comment: I thought only stack overflow had its own meta, and the rest of the se network used this meta?

Comment: Or do you meAn to ask my actual modelling question on meta.crafts.se ? Or do you mean my "where to post modelling question?" question? In other words: what question are you proposing I ask and on what exact site should I ask it?

Comment: Every site has its own child meta (in this case, [crafts.meta.se]) for questions about that site in particular, which is the perfect place to ask this question (whether latex molding is on-topic there).

Comment: If it isn't on-topic on Arts & Crafts you can ask on [tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) ....  /jk

Comment: LOL@rene - this is latex as in the rubbery stuff, not latex as in the document editor for ubernerds, but I'm sure they'll appreciate the humour when I ask :)

Comment: I'd love to see the reaction if you ask this on TeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com) and [Arts and Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com) and while it's clearly offtopic on HI, it isn't mentioned as off-topic in the help center of the AaC.

I'd suggest you to head over to the meta AaC and ask if it's on-topic or not, like Nathan Tuggy suggested. Or you can just ask directly, if you're not embarrassed with downvotes and on-hold questions of course.